Rpyc dosen't transfer any methods or libraries to client
So I wanted to make a C2 server that transfers methods and libraries to its clients but because of some reason it just dosen't want to. I have checked the version and it's 6.0.0 and there is no firewalls on pc. Code dosen't spit out any erros except; AttributeError: 'SlaveService' object has no attribute exposed_add, so I assume it's some kind of bug in my  code.
Here is my C2:
import rpyc
conn = rpyc.classic.connect("localhost", 18812)
while True:
   class MyService(rpyc.Service):
        def on_connect(self, conn):
            print("connection made")
        def on_disconnect(self, conn):
            print("connection closed")
        def exposed_add(self, x, y):
            resukt = x + y
            print(resukt)
            print("jesus")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from rpyc.utils.server import ThreadedServer
    server = ThreadedServer(Myservice, port=18812,protocol_config = {"allow_public_attrs" : True} )
    server.start()


There is right identations on the code above I just don't know how to put it here(this is my first post ever)
I have tried transfering the libraries to the client but either it spits out the error I mentioned above or it just says welcome and goodbye. When client asks for an import it dosen't work but when I do the conn.execute('for loop') it works perfectly and even gives me the result back. I tried importing the libraries through the conn.execute method but it still gives me the same error from above
Here is my client:
import rpyc

conn = rpyc.connect("localhost", 18812)
rez = conn.root.exposed_add(5, 6)
print(rez)

I'm a begginer at this but I'm trying to learn so go easy on me if there is a big mistake somewhere

The prefix exposed_ is there for the benefit of RPyC, to mark which functions are available to the connecting clients. That prefix is parsed out, eliminated, when the server actually starts.
Functions not prefixed with exposed_ are internal to the server, not callable from the outside world.
If you write a function called exposed_add(), you call it from your client script with conn.root.add()
